# Grabing the anchor from the LI whose ID is same as the cell's ID

Tags: jquery

I have below is the html code for TD which gets appended after matching the IDs from below LI HTML code

```
<td style="border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-left-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid" id="Communication">
    Communication Science Course
</td>

<li id="CommunicationTooltip"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="toolTip">
    <img src="/images/q_mark.gif" alt="" /><span style="width: 300px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 55px;">Testing
    Communication.</span></a> 
</li>

<td style="border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-left-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid" id="Communication_1">
    Communication Science Course II
</td>

<li id="Communication_1Tooltip"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="toolTip">
    <img src="/images/q_mark.gif" alt="" /><span style="width: 300px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 55px;">Testing
    Communication II.</span></a> 
</li>
```

Here is Jquery which matches the relative **IDs** and takes tag from above **LI** and further append in above **TD**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

        // bind to cells with an ID attribute
        $("table > tbody > tr > td[id]").each(function() 
        {                

            // grab the anchor from the LI whose ID starts with the cell's ID
            var $tooltip = $("div:hidden li[id^=" + $(this).attr("id") + "] a");

            //alert($tooltip);

            // append it to the current cell
            $(this).append($tooltip);

        });
});
```

if you see the above HTML code we have two different LI IDs **(Communication and Communication_1)**,The issue is that it works fine if I use **Communication1** as second **ID**, however when I use **Communication_1** it appends the ANCHOR tag to **Communication** TD, if you check above Jquery it matches the LI IDs starting with same ID, However I want it that it should match perfect LI ID not starting with same ID.

Please amend the above Jquery code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure of what you want to achieve, I can only guess the issue is you are using 'startwith' to match the IDs. Since the toolip ID is always "idOfTDTooltip", why not match them exactly?

```
var $tooltip = $("div:hidden li[id='" + $(this).attr("id") + "ToolTip'] a");
```

Alternatively, case-insensitive comparing of the ID with ID+'tooltip':

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind to cells with an ID attribute
    $("table > tbody > tr > td[id]").each(function() 
    {                
        appendTooltip($(this), $(this).attr('id'));
    });
});

function appendTooltip(obj, theId) //find and append tooltip
{
  $("div:hidden li[id^='" + theId + "'] a").each(function(){
    if($(this).parent().attr('id').toLowerCase() === (theId + "tooltip").toLowerCase()) {
      obj.append($(this));
      return;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my "Tooltip" text can be small case as well, I mean it can be "tooltip" also instead of "ToolTip", please suggest!

Comment: @Solution: I've added an alternative method in my code. Not tested but you'll get the gist. I'm sure there are better ways, just not coming to me :P

Comment: Hi it didn't worked for me it is not even coming inside $tooltip.each(function(idx) function, please suggest